# How to filter IQueryable with an OR statement in a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to filter a list of products by **Color Ids** and i want to show all products with this list of colors, and i am applying pagination so that is why i am using IQueryable.

I tried doing such thing but the products result is not getting all the object like:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productsParams.ColorsId))
        {
            var colorsIds = productsParams.ColorsId.Split(',');
            List<Product> filtredProducts = new List<Product>();

            foreach (var color in colorsIds)
            {
                var productColors = products.Where(c => c.ColorId == int.Parse(color));
                filtredProducts.AddRange(productColors);
            }
            products = filtredProducts.AsQueryable();
        }
```

but an error is occurring `System.InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable<YounesCo_Backend.Models.Product>. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.`

what can i do to filter my list of products with multiple colors?

Comment: What about `products  = products.Where(p => colorsIds.Any(c => int.Parse(c) ==  p.ColorId).AsQueryable();`?

Comment: i tried using this but another error happen `The LINQ expression 'Where<Product>(
    source: Where<Product>(
        source: DbSet<Product>, 
        predicate: (p) => p.Deleted == False), 
    predicate: (p) => Any<string>(
        source: (Unhandled parameter: __colorsIds_0), 
        predicate: (c) => (Nullable<int>)Parse(c) == p.ColorId))' could not be translated.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. one (And)

   ```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productsParams.ColorsId))
   {
       var colorsIds = productsParams.ColorsId.Split(',');
       var query = products.AsQueryable() ;
       foreach (var color in colorsIds)
       {
           query = query.Where(c => c.ColorId == int.Parse(color));               
       }
       List<Product> filtredProducts = query.ToList();
   }
   ```
2. two (OR)

   ```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productsParams.ColorsId))
   {
       int[]  colorsIds = ToIntArray(productsParams.ColorsId.Split(','));
       List<Product> filtredProducts = products.Where(c => colorsIds.Contains(c.ColorId)).ToList(); 
   }
   ```

you must implement ToIntArrat(List list) method,
([Convert List<String[]> to Array int[][]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599671/convert-liststring-to-array-int))

Comment: but i did't implement ToIntArray because i am a lazy person, so what i did is i checked for `products.Where(c => colorsIds.Contains(c.ColorId.toString())).ToList()` :p

Comment: i added a link for implementing that inside the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599671/convert-liststring-to-array-int